# position: fixed with keyboard active on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, css, iphone, safari, responsive

I am trying to use position fixed to work well on iOS devices.

This is how it looks when the keyboard has not opened:

[Screenshot: No keyboard active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwo1q.png)

For the above chat window I have used this piece of code:

```
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
```

When I tap the input box (to write a message), keyboard opens up and the top part becomes hidden with the screen zoomed in and it looks like this:

[Screenshot: When Keyboard is active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q93rF.jpg)

I think ios is ignoring `top: 0` when the keyboard opens up. What can I do to avoid that?

There is no issue as such on chrome.